# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier after Facebook login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I trying to capture the results of user Facebook details after they have login, instantiate a view controller and show the controller.

However the weird thing is that when I have that `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` code inside my `getFBUserData()` method, it exits after `FBSDKGraphRequest`. When I remove that chunk of commented codes, it executes the storing of variables perfectly.

I've also tried placing the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` code after `self.getFBUserData()`, and it also doesn't store the variables again.

I need help with storing the variables, and then execute the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` displaying the stored variables.

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!){

    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()

                }
            }
            return;
        }
        else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Limited Connectivity", message: "We're unable to log you in. Please check your network connectivity.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
                UIAlertAction in
            }

            alertController.addAction(action1)
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            fbLoginManager.logOut()
            return;
        }
    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                self.strName = (result.objectForKey("name") as? String)!
                self.strID = (result.objectForKey("id") as? String)!
                self.strEmail = (result.objectForKey("email") as? String)!
                let strPictureURL: String = (result.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as? String)!
                self.fbProfileImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strPictureURL)!)!)!

                /*
                let displayViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChooseNameViewController") as! ChooseNameViewController

                displayViewController.email = self.strEmail
                displayViewController.id = self.strID
                displayViewController.name = self.strName
                displayViewController.profilePic = self.fbProfileImage

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(displayViewController, animated: true)
                */
            }
            else{
                let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
                return
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As this method `FBSDKGraphRequest` make  asych call on back ground thread.You need to do UI related work on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                let displayViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChooseNameViewController") as! ChooseNameViewController
                displayViewController.email = self.strEmail
                displayViewController.id = self.strID
                displayViewController.name = self.strName
                displayViewController.profilePic = self.fbProfileImage

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(displayViewController, animated: true)
    });
```

Comment: Ahhh ok... Just in case for people who faced the same issue, I placed this code after the curly braces of `self.fbProfileImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strPictureURL)!)!)!`